# Lob is closed. ERRORCODE=-4470, SQLSTATE=null

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, db2, websphere-commerce

I am using IBM websphere commerce and db2, have following piece of code

```
Clob clobVar = null;
if (result.elementAt(3) != null)
    clobVar = (Clob) result.elementAt(3);

if (clobVar == null) {
    infoTable.put("EInfo", "");
} else {
    stringTemp = clobVar.getSubString(1, (int) clobVar.length());
    infoTable.put("EInfo", stringTemp); 
}
```

Code works fine till

```
clobVar = (Clob) result.elementAt(3);
```

but as soon as execution comes to

```
stringTemp = clobVar.getSubString(1, (int) clobVar.length());
```

System throws an exception

**[jcc][10120][11936][4.3.111] Invalid operation: Lob is closed. ERRORCODE=-4470, SQLSTATE=null**

What I am doing wrong?

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 21):

This issue can be solved by adding `progressiveStreaming=2;` argument to the connection url

The fully specified Connection URL was to be given as below:

```
jdbc:db2://localhost:50000/SAMPLE:progressiveStreaming=2;
```

Incase you have exception on that parameter add the following to it:

```
jdbc:db2://localhost:50000/SAMPLE:driverType=4;fullyMaterializeLobData=true;fullyMaterializeInputStreams=true;progressiveStreaming=2;progresssiveLocators=2;
```

It is preferred to use `db2jcc4.jar`

Comment: You saved me! The first trick worked. (Please don't ommit the ; at the end) Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Since it is too long for a comment and I was researching for some time, here is some **explanation** why `progressiveStreaming=2;` works:

It is a special parameter for the DB2 JDBC driver that changes the way the driver handles Large Objects (LOBs).

If the parameter is included in the JDBC URL, it tells the DB2 JDBC driver to stream LOB data "progressively". This means that the driver will not load the LOB data into memory all at once, but will instead load it in small chunks or "chunks" as you access the data.

In most cases, it is possible to access LOB data even after the ResultSet is closed. This is because the JDBC driver can still access the underlying LOB data in the database even after the ResultSet is closed.

Here is an example of how you could use the parameter in your JDBC URL:

```
String url = "jdbc:db2://localhost:50000/MYDB:progressiveStreaming=2;";
```

Please note that the `progressiveStreaming=2;` parameter only works with certain versions of the DB2 JDBC driver. Make sure that you are using a supported driver version.

Answer (score -1):

```
If everything has worked earlier with same code...but the issue came up after db2 db change, then try below configuration..
db2set DB2_RESTRICT_DDF=TRUE
```

It worked for me..